# Start of String into new column

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have finally finished importing this huge text file into SSMS. Since the format was Ragged Right I accidentally placed two columns into one. So I added a fresh column with the appropriate header. However now in my column `def_nam` I have a 4 characters in front of the actual column value that do not belong there.

Example:

```
def_name                        rea
PLEA WUNSCH, JOHN ROGER         NULL
SFJS VILLARREAL, JACOB ANDERS   NULL
DISP TORRES, STEVEN             NULL
DISP ATKINSON, JAMES FRANKLIN   NULL
HEAR GODARZI, FOROUZAN          NULL
NTRL REYES, MANUEL JR           NULL
HEAR HANLON, THOMAS JOSEPH      NULL
HEAR HANLON, THOMAS JOSEPH      NULL
DISP WILSON, MELISSA WAYNETTE   NULL
HEAR PROSPER, TIMOTHY DANIEL    NULL
```

So the Objective is the following: I would like to split the string in this column grab all the characters BEFORE the FIRST space and insert that value into my new EMPTY column called `rea`

Thus we would end with this.

```
def_name                    rea
WUNSCH, JOHN ROGER          PLEA
VILLARREAL, JACOB ANDERS    SFJS
TORRES, STEVEN              DISP
ATKINSON, JAMES FRANKLIN    DISP
GODARZI, FOROUZAN           HEAR
REYES, MANUEL JR            NTRL
HANLON, THOMAS JOSEPH       HEAR
HANLON, THOMAS JOSEPH       HEAR
WILSON, MELISSA WAYNETTE    DISP
PROSPER, TIMOTHY DANIEL     HEAR
```

What would be the best Query to write for something like this? Considering that I have over 3 million rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably do something like this.

```
update YourTable
set rea = LEFT(def_name, 4)
    , def_name = stuff(def_name, 1, 5, '')
```

Comment: The stuff would null out the values in def_name, `update t set rea = left(def_name, 4), def_name = substring(def_name, 6, len(def_name))` would work though.

Comment: @jpw - what do you mean it would NULL them? It would stuff an empty string into the first 5 characters which is what the OP wants. The substring you suggested would accomplish the same thing. Just a different syntax to get there. :)

Comment: I tried it, and it set all def_name to null. That was what I meant :) I guess stuff should work, but there's just something wrong here.

Comment: Ah yeah, that fixed it :)

Comment: Is `stuff` materially faster than `substring`?

Comment: @ChrisF no it isn't any faster. It is however less coding. In this case either approach is going to hit each and every row so it doesn't much matter.

Comment: @ChrisF It might be considering the substring option has one more function call for `len`. With the limited sample they show the same execution plan. I would guess it won't make much difference.

Comment: @jpw Is it safe to use the one you posted? If I wanted to try it with my first row will this work?

`UPDATE TOP TexasHarrisCountyCountyRecords set rea = LEFT(def_name, 4)
    , def_name = stuff(def_name, 1, 5, '')`

Comment: @Lostaunaum Yes. MS SQL uses the existing values for updates, so the order of set clauses are not important - you could update def_name first and rea second and you would get the same results. (But as always - be sure to have a backup or copy of the data before you update, one never knows what might go wrong :) ) Lose the `TOP` though - it has no place in the update (at least not without an order by clause)

Comment: @jpw awesome. Yeah the TOP is only to test it out on the very first row to make sure it works. I got a copy of the data its just that its so big and it takes so long to get it in my server (its rackspace hosted and our internet is terrible) That i dont want to mess it up.